# Reading in times correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which gives times in this format: `12:05:56 AM` in the column `utc`

Just reading it as is into a new dataframe gives back weirdly enough this: `05:56.0`

I want to just have the original time.

I tried using the `datetime.strptime` function and `date_parser` parameter, but I received an error:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%H:%M:%S') for d in dates]

path = r'res/frbcat_20190913.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path,parse_dates=['utc'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

This was the error:
`ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'`

Comment: Because you have `AM` and `PM` you should use `datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%H:%M:%S %p')`.  If you provide more time samples, and say whether you want dates or just times in output, a more detailed response can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%H:%M:%S %p') for d in dates]
```

Quoting the [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation:

> '%p' Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.